# Python pandas. Need to aggregate if column value is in another comma separated value column of second dataframe

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, pandas-groupby

I have 2 data frames sample, with names changed

```
df1 = 
| Comp_code | DepartmentListA | DepartmentListB |
| --------  | --------------- | --------------- |
| Code_1    | "Dept1"         | "Dept3"         |
| Code_2    | "Dept2"         | "Dept4"         |
| Code_3    | "Dept4, Dept5"  | "Dept1"         |
| Code_4    | "Dept1,Dept5, Dept6"  | "Dept3, Dept4"  |
```

df2 = with just department and revenue

```
| DepartmentList | Revenue|  Gross Margin|
| --------------- | -------| -------|
| "Dept1"         | 1000         | 500
| "Dept2"         | 2000         | 0
| "Dept3,         | 5000         | 900
| "Dept4"         | 5000         | 200
| "Dept5"         | 7000         | -100
| "Dept6"         | 8000         | 2500
```

**I would like my final df to have company codes and total revenue and gross margin. Summing up totals of departments in column A and B.**
I am not able to iterate and join because of the comma separated string of departments. My final DF should be something like this

expected df =

```
| Comp_code | GrossRev| Tot Margin|
| --------  | --------------- | --------------- |
| Code_1    | 6000         | 1400         |
| Code_2    | 7000         | 200         |
| Code_3    | 13000  | 600         |
| Code_4    | 26000  | 4000  |
```

Also the data frames are both a couple of million rows and some department lists (comma separated values) are about 100 in number. Would be good if there was a performant way of doing this.

TIA,

Comment: why Code_1 Dept1 have 6000?

Comment: Are you using Python 2.7? Please note: the [minimum recommended version](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/install.html) for pandas as of now is Python 3.8. And Python in general, [sunsetted Python 2](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/) as of Jan 1, 2020 with recommendation to upgrade.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I am on 2.7 and pandas ver 0.24. So melt and explode dont work though in my local they seem to be perfect. Is there any solution with older versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with the following

```
df["all"] = ((df["DepartmentListA"] + 
              ", " + 
              df["DepartmentListB"]).str.split("[\\s,]+"))

df3 = df.explode("all")

df3 = (pd.merge(df3, df2, left_on='all', 
               right_on='Comp_code', suffixes=('', '_y'))
               .groupby("Comp_code")
                .agg({'Revenue': ['sum'], 'Gross Margin': 'sum'}).reset_index())

df3.columns = df3.columns.droplevel(-1)
print(df3)

  Comp_code  Revenue  Gross Margin
0    Code_1     6000          1400
1    Code_2     7000           200
2    Code_3    13000           600
3    Code_4    26000          4000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `melt`+`explode` to get individual row per department, then `merge` with `df2` to get the data, and finally `groupby`+`sum` to aggregate the `sum`:

```
(df1.melt(id_vars='Comp_code')
    .assign(value=lambda d: d['value'].str.split(r',\s*'))
    .explode('value')
    .merge(df2, left_on='value', right_on='DepartmentList')
    .groupby('Comp_code').agg({'Revenue': 'sum', 'Gross Margin': 'sum'})
)
```

output:

```
           Revenue  Gross Margin
Comp_code                       
Code_1        6000          1400
Code_2        7000           200
Code_3       13000           600
Code_4       26000          4000
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am on 2.7 and pandas ver 0.24. So melt and explode don't work, though in my local system they seem to be perfect. Is there any solution with older versions?

Comment: Without traceback, hard to know what went wrong. That said, python2 is not supported anymore, so is pandas 0.24, you should really stop using them and upgrade to something more recent.